# Undefined variable _POST

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, php, forms

Using 3.1.1 with debug on, I am getting following notice.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: _POST in <filepath> on line 1000
```

Code at line 1000 is

```
$data = $_POST
```

Why am I getting this notice? How can I remove this particular notice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if it is a non-empty POST request:

```
if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] and ! empty ( $_POST )
{   // don't forget to sanitize these data!
    $data = $_POST;
}
else
{
    return FALSE;
}
```